# Find all those graphs $G$ of order $n \geq 4$ such that the subgraph induced by every three vertices of $G$ is a tree.

Tags: graph-theory

I thought a graph like this did not even exist? I suppose, at least, I cannot think of one that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the graph $G$ as a subgraph of a complete graph $K_n$. Then $G$ must contain exactly two edges from each triangle in $K_n$. It easily follows that $G$ must contain exactly two-thirds of the edges of $K_n$. This is impossible for $n=5$ since $K_5$ has $10$ edges, not divisible by $3$; so every graph of order $5$ (or greater) has an induced graph on $3$ vertices which is not a tree.

This leaves only the case $n=4$. The graph $G$ must have exactly $4$ vertices, exactly $4$ edges, and no triangles; the only such graph is $K_{2,2}=C_4$, which works.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: For $n \geq 5$, there must be a vertex of degree $3$.  If there's no triangles, it's neighbours must not be adjacent, but this is a contradiction.

To prove the existence of such a vertex:

- The subgraph induced by $\{1,2,3\}$ has a vertex of degree $2$, let's say it's vertex $1$.
- Now consider the subgraph induced by $\{1,4,5\}$.